# How to display information about active and inactive SP2007 workflows?

Tags: workflow, 2007, powershell

I'm new to the Workflow Object Model in MOSS 2007, and trying to find an example of C# code that does the same as this SP2010 PowerShell?

```
//get all the lists
$lists = $web.Lists
foreach ($list in $lists)
{
    //loop through and print out the workflow name and number of running instances
    $associations=@()
    foreach ($listassociation in $list.WorkflowAssociations)
    {
        $associations += $($listassocation.name)
        if($associations.count -ge 1)
        {
            Write-Host "Description:" $listassociation.Description
            Write-Host "Running Instances: " $listassocation.RunningInstances
        }
    }
}
```

Kris

Answer (score 0):

In terms of iterating through all sites, in your site collection, and outputting the workflows associated, you can do the following powershell script.

```
$site = Get-SPSite("your-site-url");
$site.AllWebs | foreach { $_.Lists | foreach { $_.WorkflowAssociations | foreach { 
  write-host "Site:" $_.ParentWeb.Url ", List:" $_.ParentList.Title ", Workflow:" $_.Name
} } }
```

You can slightly modify to extrapolate your needed additional properties.

Comment: Quinn, thanks for the code, but unfortunately, this only worked for me in SP2010. For MOSS 2007 workflow details, I ended up using the .NET code above from within a PowerShell script.